# lxml not supports multiple attributes filter on xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I want to select nodes with multiple attributes using xpath

is there any workaround for my problem ?

`node.xpath('.//td[@colspan=6 @class="mbw"]')`

```
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1507, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:52198)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:152124)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:151097)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 212, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:150896)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your xpath expression is missing logical operator (`and` or `or`) for combining each attribute criteria, for example :

```
node.xpath('.//td[@colspan=6 and @class="mbw"]')
```

Comment: thank you so much, i could find useful answer with  googleing `xpath lxml multiple attributes`,  u saved me ~~thx a lot